Filter Header and Copy Row Using VBA
I have problem with this code because it stop after filtering those 3 criteria. And then vba only copied the header from sheet ALL while it should have copied data start from below header that have been filtered.
I don't have any idea what srong with the code as it was work perfectly fine. Thank you in advance!
Function GetTheLastRow(sheetName As String) As Long
    'Function to get last row in the sheet
    Dim sheetTarget As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set sheetTarget = wb.Sheets("ALL")
    lastRow = sheetTarget.Cells(sheetTarget.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    GetTheLastRow = lastRow
End Function
Sub ExportASI()
    Dim sourceSheet As String, targetSheet As String
    Dim lastRowSourceSheet As Long
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    sourceSheet = "ALL"
    targetSheet = "BATCH"
    
    lastRowSourceSheet = GetTheLastRow(sourceSheet)
    
    Sheets(sourceSheet).Range("A2:BL" & lastRowSourceSheet).AutoFilter field:=57, Criteria1:="LOLOS SORTIR"
    Sheets(sourceSheet).Range("A2:BL" & lastRowSourceSheet).AutoFilter field:=63, Criteria1:="New Batch"
    Sheets(sourceSheet).Range("A2:BL" & lastRowSourceSheet).AutoFilter field:=64, Criteria1:="#N/A"
    
    Sheets(sourceSheet).Range("C2:BE" & lastRowSourceSheet).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    Sheets(targetSheet).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial

'Export sheet BATCH
    Dim fName
    Sheets("BATCH").Copy
    With ActiveSheet
        .UsedRange.Copy
        .Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    fName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:="", Filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", Title:="Save As")
    With ActiveWorkbook
        .SaveAs Filename:=fName
        .Close True
    End With
End Sub


Really need .UsedRange.Copy in the Export sheet BATCH part?

Try placing Stop after the third AutoFitler. When code stops, look to the respective sheet to see if it shows what you think it should. If yes, try running the code line by line, using F8 and see what the code does. In this way you can understand where the code stops doing what you need and seeing that code line you may understand the reason, I think. If not, edit your question, explain what you did and which is the line behaving strange. It will be helpful for us to help you, I think...

Is header on Row 1 or Row 2 on sourceSheet?

Why not Sheets(sourceSheet).Range("C2:BE" & lastRowSourceSheet).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ?  There's no need to copy each column individually.

@taller header on row 1 on sourceSheet

@TimWilliams oh you are right. I change it into that. But, it doesn't solve the problem.

@FaneDuru I think the copy and paste code line is the problem, but I don't get it why it happens. Is it because the filtered row didn't start from C2?

@Blackcat  is there any other ideas?

If the header is on row 1, the code to apply autofilter should be Sheets(sourceSheet).Range("A1:BL" & lastRowSourceSheet).AutoFilter.

@taller without the "field" its giving failed expression.

Of course, you need the arguments. I meant change A2 to A1.

@taller oh ok. But, still not copying the rest of the row :'

It's difficult to debugging code w/o your file.

@taller i've found the solution. I'll put he answer below

So instead of copy from each column I'll use this line instead and it works.


Dim Rng As Range
    Set Rng = Sheets(sourceSheet).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Rng.Copy Destination:=Sheets("BATCH").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)




Try Sheets(sourceSheet).UsedRange.Copy Destination:=Sheets("BATCH").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp). SpecialCells is not necessary because Copy method only copies visible cells.
